# footer pierde posición al cambiar tamaño de ventana

Tags: html, css

estoy realizando un proyecto y en la página index logré posicionar el footer al fondo de la página, pero al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana (minimizar tamaño) veo que la pag hace scroll y el footer no queda en el fondo sino que queda como si tuviera el valor position: sticky. en el ejemplo pueden ver sin poner en pantalla completa.

no se me ocurre alguna manera de solucionar esto, espero y puedan ayudarme.

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient( 90deg, green, #ffb744 );
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-footer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #099700;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    cualquier texto
  </div>
  
  <footer class="site-footer">
      aqui va el copyright
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Con position `absolute`, el `bottom: 0` significa pegado al actual fondo de la pantalla. Obviamente si el contenido sigue para abajo, como tienes `position: absolute` el "footer" se queda en donde estaba en el momento que se dibujó. Si lo que quieres es que vaya al fondo *"de todo"*, prueba a ponerle un `position: relative;` y verás como se coloca al final del `div.container`.

Comment: el problema benito es que al usar position: relative queda un pequeño espacio entre el footer y el fondo de la pag. no he dado como solucionar eso, por eso opté por usar position: absolute, ya que con el no queda espacio pero al hacer scroll genera el problema de mi pregunta. he intentado ponerle height: 100% al body y html pero nada

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

- Agregar altura minima (`min-height`) de 100vh al body.
- Cambiar el valor de la altura del elemento `.container` de  `300px` a `auto`

**UPDATE 1**

Agrega:

- `position: relative` al body
- `position: absolute` al footer

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, green, #ffb744 );
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative
}

.site-footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #099700;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <div class="container">
    cualquier texto
  </div>

  <footer class="site-footer">
    aqui va el copyright
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: sigue con el mismo problema. sale el scroll de la pag y sigue como sticky

Comment: Revisa el update a ver si te funciona

Comment: sube más el footer. hay algo de materialize que me produce el problema pero no doy con él

Comment: No comprendo tu comentario @Marcus, que yo suba mas el footer? o que el footer subio mas al utilizar la solucion que te di?.
Si es algo de materialize, debes copiar todo el codigo amigo para ver la verdera problematica.

Comment: Si el problema es de materialize te exorto a que modifiques la pregunta para ver el codigo o que crees una pregunta nueva y etiquetes de manera correcta (`materialize`)!

Comment: sí debí formular mejor la pregunta. busqué y busqué y al parecer no dí con alguna clase de Materialize que me de ese problema. pero encontré una solución: a <body> le puse display: grid, display-template-rows: auto 1fr auto y min-height: 100vh y a <footer> le puse margin-top: auto, eliminando bottom: 0 y position: absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Solo bastaría cambiar la posición de tu clase `.site-footer`. en tu código lo tienes así:

```
.site-footer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #099700;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

De la cual, deberías cambiarlo por `position: relative;` para que el footer se coloque al final del contenedor de encima:

```
.site-footer {
    position: relative; /* aquí el cambio */
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #099700;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

El resultado sería así:

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, green, #ffb744);
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #099700;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    height: 500px; /* Le aumentamos el height para ver el cambio */
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        cualquier texto
    </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
        aqui va el copyright
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda. el problema de usar position: relative es que entre el footer y el final de la pag queda un espaciado. le he puesto height 100% al body y al html pero no queda totalmente al fondo

Comment: Yo no veo ningún espacio, el footer se irá totalmente al final de la página así agregues contenido encima. Puedes agregarle `margin: 0` para quitar los espacios que mencionas

Comment: sí, hay algo en el código que me da ese problema pero no logro dar con el... seguiré intentando

Comment: Ok está bien, nos avisas

Comment: para estructurar el index estoy usando clases de Materialize. estoy seguro de que hay algun valor en dichas clases que me da el problema pero no doy con ella.

Comment: ya encontré solución! utilizando display: grid. puse los siguientes valores a <body> display: grid; | grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto; | min-height: 100vh; y a .site-footer margin-top: auto; eliminando bottom: 0; y position: absolute;